# MySQL query error, query wont work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

im trying to run a query in my servlet controller that  matches the id with the name in my database. The query im using is

```
String query="SELECT *FROM entry WHERE id ="+id2+"AND name="+sname;
```

but i keep getting an error that says

> "right syntax to use near 'name=Mary Jane' at line 1"

im pretty sure my query is right , when i run it with out the AND name part it works. so i have no idea why it wont work with the AND name part , unless my query is wrong for that side. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating string is first step to **SQL Injection attack!**

If you want to go this path add spaces:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM entry WHERE id = "+id2+" AND name= "+sname;
```

if needed add `'` to quote string literal:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM entry WHERE id = "+id2+" AND name= '"+sname + "'";
```

**EDIT:**

You really should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) like:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM entry WHERE id = ? AND name = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

ps.setInt(1, id2);
ps.setString(2, sname);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my comment after you updated the answer. Anyway, I would **strongly recommend** to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) here.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Yup Prepared Statement is the way. Concatenating string is good only for school homeworks and it is very bad practice

Comment: thank you for the help , i will use prepared statements , but i wanted to make sure my querys were working first , thanks you very much for all the help!